# ¿Cómo usar imágenes con j2html?

Tags: java, jframe, j2html

Estoy usando una librería llamada j2html en Java, que sirve para introducir código html con unos métodos. Yo lo estoy usando para crear una especie de "página" que se muestre en un 'JFrame'. Esto es posible introduciendo un label y usando el método '.setText(Código HTML)'. lo que me pasa es que no consigo que carguen las imágenes, que las guardo en un paquete llamado img. Para cargar dicha imagen hay que usar el método 'img().withSrc("/img/menu.png")', pero la imagen no carga. He probado a guardarla en distintas rutas y no aparece.

```
jTextPane1.setText(html(
        header(
            title("Documentación")
        ),
        body(                 
            h1("Documentación").withClass("title"), 
            h2("Índice").withClass("title"),
            ul(
                li(b("1. Menú principal")),
                li(b("2. Dividir")),
                li(b("3. Eiminar"))                    
            ),

            img().withSrc("/img/menu.png"),            
        )              
    ).render());
```

Esta es mi estructura de archivos. El JFrame donde del código anterior está en el package JFrame y se llama ´ManualFrame´
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que me muestra en el frame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con `getClass().getResource("/img/menu.png"))`, no sé si `img` tiene un padre, pues no se aprecia en la captura de pantalla, lo cierto es que deberías poner la ruta completa, considera que debe encontrar la imagen no sólo en tiempo de depuración, sino también cuando hayas distribuido la aplicación, por eso es conveniente usar siempre `getClass().getResource()`

Comment: Justo, ha funcionado. Muchas gracias.